# Option in graphicx package ->shifted document

Tags: graphics

I'm using sharelatex to write a report document, i'm using a template (thesis template) to write it. I have a problem at the very beginning...

The package graphicx is used with the option DVIPS (`\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}`)
but the logo (picture) inserted in the first page does not appear:

`\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{./pictures/logopm}
    \end{center}
  \end{figure}`

(i verified all my paths and extensions are corect), so i have this pdf:
[image]

so, the picture doesnt appear, but when i remove the option[dvips] 
and replace by : `\usepackage{graphicx}` or `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}` ..
the picture appear but the whole document text is shifted on the right side, without modifying anything else!! like that :

[image]

So i dont want that my document be shifted each time i insert a picture in.

I thanks you very much if somebody can provide an answer, i think it's little thing...
Have a nice day !

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sounds as if your template is buggy ...

Comment: you should almost never use the `dvips` or `pdftex` options, let the package choose tthe correct option depending whether you  are using pdftex or latex. If you specify  the wrong option most things will not work.

Comment: ok thanks a lot, but when i dont specify the options `dvips`,

Comment: or `pdftex` like`\usepackage{graphicx}` the document is still shifted..

Comment: so i dont really know...

Comment: if you specify `dvips` and use pdflatex not dvips then nothing will work, images will not include, page size will be wrong colours will not work.  Most likely what you are seeing is that when the correct default is used the page size is being set

Comment: your latex is probably specifying A4 but you are viewing in US letter (or the other way round). You have not shown any relevant code, perhaps you just need to add `[a4paper]` to the documentclass line

Comment: yes its specify a4paper in my documentclassline:

Comment: so maybe im viewing in a wrong way like you say, us letter or else, do you how to fix it?

Comment: `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}            
\usepackage{rotating}` here is the beginning of my documentclassline

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphics}
```

Which if you use pdflatex will default the `[pdftex]` option  and as well as allowing graphics inclusion using pdftex-specific code it declares the page size in the pdf to match the declare A4 page size.

If you do not load graphics, or you load it in a form where it can not work, by specifying an incorrect driver option such as `dvips` then the page size declared in the PDF will be whatever size was specified when TeX was installed, which (if you are in Italy) ought to be A4 but could be US letter. If you typeset an A4 document but use a PDf page size for US letter then the effect is as you describe, the layout within the text block is correct but the text block will be mis-placed on the page.

Comment: `\usepackage{graphicx}` (not graphics)?

Comment: @Zarko same thing in this case:-) (all the driver option stuff, and setting the page size is in `graphics` and only applies to  `graphicx` as that includes `graphics`

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with this exact template for my thesis at Politecnico of Milan.

The solution I found was to comment the lines:

```
\setlength{\paperwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{24cm}
```

I've also changed the graphic package from

```
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
```

to

```
\usepackage{graphics}
```

It is currently working fine, preserving the page format.